# Oracle SQL update table row by row

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update a DB-table, row by row, incrementing the ID for each row.

**From** a table like this

```
ID Foo Bar
------------
0  a   v
0  b   x
0  c   y
0  d   z
...
```

**To**

```
ID Foo Bar
------------
1  a   v
2  b   x
3  c   y
4  d   z
...
```

Is there a faster and better whay than this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.update_foo_bar
AS
    v_i    int := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM TEMP_FOO_BAR)
  LOOP   
        UPDATE TEMP_FOO_BAR fb
          SET fb.ID = v_i
            WHERE rec.Foo = fb.Foo
            AND rec.Bar = fb.Bar;

            v_i := v_i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

What I would like to do is simply assign the row-ID instead of checking the whole table on each iteration with the "where"-clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ID` values in your expected output can only be gotten by assuming some *order* in the records in your table.  Assuming the `Foo` column determines this order, you can generate the output you expect using a simple query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Foo) ID,
    Foo,
    Bar
FROM TEMP_FOO_BAR
ORDER BY ID;
```

The problem with using an update here is that as soon as you add more data to the table, you might be forced to do another update.

If you need `ID` to behave like an auto increment/identity column, then make it one, and let Oracle worry about maintaining the sequence as you add new data.

Comment: It is odd that this was accepted.  Although totally correct for a `SELECT` query, I interpret the question as asking for an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you delete that column and then run a alter table and add a column and a constraint to update the value every time.